# How are strings (varchar) passed into SQL stored procedures?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to pass a string into a stored procedure. My code is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddCondition
    @CondName varchar(50),
    @CondDesc varchar(50)
AS
    DECLARE @CondID int

    --This code gets the next ID for the table
    SET @CondID = (SELECT MAX([Condition ID]) FROM [dbo].[Tube Conditions]) + 1
    SET @CondID = ISNULL(@CondID,1)

    --This code adds records to the table
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Tube Conditions] ([Condition ID],[Condition Name],[Description])
    VALUES (@CondID, @CondName, @CondDesc)
GO
```

I try to execute with:

```
DECLARE @aName varchar(50), @aDesc varchar(50)
SET @aName = 'Lathed'
SET @aDesc = 'The tube has been lathed to size'

EXECUTE AddCondition @aName, @aDesc
GO
```

But I keep getting the error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure AddCondition, Line 51
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Lathed' to data type int.

This same process has worked when dealing with int and float values, so I'm not sure what I'm missing here. I am using SQL Server 2014 Management Studio with SQL Server Express.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: (1) your errormessage says error in line 51, there is no line 51 in your 5 line code. (2) you could use an identity column instead of that get next id thingy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the code you have posted there is only 1 thing that will generate the error you specify, and that is if the `[Condition Name]` column in table `[dbo].[Tube Conditions]` is of type int, rather than varchar as expected by the insert statement.

As an aside: this is a *very* dangerous way to generate the next ID in a table - its screaming for concurrency issues when 2 records get inserted at the same time. SQL will generate this identity for you, look it up.

Comment: You were exactly right. I can't believe I didn't think of that. You can probably tell I'm pretty new to SQL, so I also appreciate the advice.  Looks like using identities is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Jamiec you probably have [dbo].[Tube Conditions] of type int

a single statement is a transaction

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Tube Conditions] ([Condition ID],[Condition Name],[Description])
SELECT MAX(isnull([Condition ID],0)) + 1, 'Lathed', 'The tube has been lathed to size'
FROM [dbo].[Tube Conditions]
```

Comment: Yes, a single statement is a transaction. However, this is *still not safe* unless the statement in question is executed under the `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level, rather than the default `READ COMMITTED`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I think I agree